# Unable to get current location using FusedLocationApi

Tags: android, geolocation, google-maps-android-api-2

I am trying to get users current location using FusedLocationApi using the following code. I am following the guide provided here https://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current.html

```
public class MapActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements
GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,LocationListener {
    private Toolbar mToolbar;
    private GoogleMap googleMap;
    GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    private final static int PLAY_SERVICES_RESOLUTION_REQUEST = 1000;
    private final static int CONNECTION_FAILURE_RESOLUTION_REQUEST =5000;
    private Location mLastLocation;
    private LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
    LocationManager locationManager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_map);

        mToolbar = (Toolbar)findViewById( R.id.toolbar );
        mToolbar.setTitle(R.string.title_activity_map);
        setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);

        try {
            initilizeMap();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        if (checkPlayServices()) {
            buildGoogleApiClient();
        }

        mLocationRequest = LocationRequest.create()
                .setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY)
                .setInterval(10 * 1000)        // 10 seconds, in milliseconds
                .setFastestInterval(1 * 1000);
    }

    private void initilizeMap() {
        if (googleMap == null) {
            googleMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(
                    R.id.map)).getMap();

            // check if map is created successfully or not
            if (googleMap == null) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Sorry! unable to create maps", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
            }
            googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        }
    }

    private boolean checkPlayServices() {
        int resultCode = GooglePlayServicesUtil
                .isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
        if (resultCode != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
            if (GooglePlayServicesUtil.isUserRecoverableError(resultCode)) {
                GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(resultCode, this,
                        PLAY_SERVICES_RESOLUTION_REQUEST).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "This device is not supported.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .show();
                finish();
            }
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        initilizeMap();
        checkPlayServices();
        if (mGoogleApiClient != null) {
            mGoogleApiClient.connect();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();

        if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
            mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
        }
    }

    protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .build();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.map, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (arg0.hasResolution()) {
            try {
                // Start an Activity that tries to resolve the error
                arg0.startResolutionForResult(this, CONNECTION_FAILURE_RESOLUTION_REQUEST);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            Log.e("Fail", "Location services connection failed with code " + arg0.getErrorCode());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        new GetLocation().execute();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    private class GetLocation extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            mLastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(
                    mGoogleApiClient);
            if (mLastLocation != null) {
                Log.e("If", "If");
            } else {
                Log.e("else", "else");
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPostExecute(result);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}
```

When I run the code it always shows else in log, this means that I am not getting any Location. Is there something missing? what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Thnx a ton man...it works like charm now, I was enabling gps but was not sharing the data, I did as You said, and it works fine.

Comment: Posted as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Moved from comments:

make sure you have gps enabled on your phone. When enabling gps, phone may also ask you to send data anonymously to google, you should accept it.